# Make all subdomains load the same page, how is it called/done?

Tags: php, html, subdomain

Is there a way to make all subdomains show the same page.

I got the idea somewhere you could have a page like idk information.com and if an user typed miami.information.com he would get information from that city.

Is there a way to do it?

Like making the site retrieve the first part of the subdomain and search it on the site.

Comment: There is, but it's more of a web server and DNS configuration thing than a programming thing. Voting to move to http://serverfault.com.

Comment: I second that. It's more of a configuration making the subdomains point to a specific url. For example miami.information.com actually points to information.com/miami.

Comment: I want all subdomains point to the same page, then I can modify the page with php based on the URL. I don't have any idea of how to do it. Could you give me a general direction on where to look for more info?

Answer (score 3):

The final configuration depends on the web server you'll be using but in Apache httpd you'd simply create a wildcard virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  # other configuration directives
</VirtualHost>
```

Prerequisite is that there's a `*.example.com` A (or CNAME) resource record in your zone for `example.com`. Ask your name server administrator about it.

In your PHP scripts you can then simply evaluate `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the first component of the hostname.